# Add a delay to jQuery popup?

Tags: jquery

I am developing a website that has a login popup for those that are not logged in, to get people to register or log in. However, the popup shows immediately upon the website loading, and I want either:

1. A time delay (e.g. 5000ms)
2. A scroll delay (e.g. the user scrolls to 50% down the page, and the popup shows)

This is the code for the popup from my developer. I've looked on StackOverflow on how to do it but with no luck, and I'm not great with jQuery etc.

If anyone could provide the complete code for me to test, I'd really appreciate it!

Many thanks in advance.

````
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if (!$('body').hasClass("logged-in")) {
         $.pgwModal({
            titleBar: false,
            target: '#rehub-login-popup',
            mainClassName : 'pgwModal re-user-popup-wrap',
         });
         $('.re-user-popup-wrap .rehub-errors').html('');
}
});
</script>```
````

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { setTimeout(function() {` .. your code .. `}, 5000); })`

Answer (score 1):

just wrap your code in Settimeout after document ready, like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Code written here will execute after 5 secodns");
    //write your code here.
  },5000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the quick response. Would it be possible for you to do the code for me, please? I have very little experience with jQuery. Many thanks :)

Comment: Hey Tom, I have already written code above, just take your if condiotion from your code and put it in my code where I have written //write your code here

Comment: Sorry Atul I can't get it to work, can you email the full code to me at tom@suppwow.com please?

Comment: as you mentioned in the question : the popup shows immediately, is it? is it showing ?

Comment: No, it does not show at all when I try the code, but I think I may have got it wrong, I'm not sure

Comment: I have tried all of the answers given to me so far but they do not work. I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong but I've tried lots of different codes that don't work.

Comment: ok, I will give you a custom modal, just tell me one thing, when user logged in then which exact class your HTML body has